# How to detect meta tag using jQuery in HTML, DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, meta-tags

Here is a problem I met using a PHP script to grab an HTML page and return the HTML content as a string to jQuery's AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    data: "url="+tar_url,
    url: "curl.php",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
       $("meta", $(data))// not working
       $(data).find("meta") //not working
       $("img",$(data)) //works
       $(data).find("div") //works                  
},
```

Inside the success function callback, I noticed that I could use normal selectors to get div, img, ul, etc. However, none of the above methods could select meta tags.

First, I don't know if the HTML contains any meta tags. If it contains some, I would like to select them out and parse them, etc.
Is it impossible to select those meta tags with jQuery?

Comment: there are many diffrent Meta tags, if you can make a list of the ones you are interested in, it would be a lot easier coding something for that.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem just now and came across this post while looking for a solution.  In the end, what worked for me was to use `filter( )` instead of `find( )`.

From Chrome's Javascript Console:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: $getThisURL, 
    success: function(data) { output = $(data).filter('meta'); }
});
```

Output:

```
[<meta http-equiv=​"Content-Type" content=​"text/​html;​charset=utf-8">​,
<meta name=​"color:​Background" content=​"#262626">​,
<meta name=​"color:​Text" content=​"#fff">​,
<meta name=​"color:​Links" content=​"#ffbc00">​,
<meta name=​"if:​Show notes" content=​"1">​,
<meta name=​"robots" content=​"noindex">​,
<meta charset=​"utf-8">​,
<meta http-equiv=​"x-dns-prefetch-control" content=​"off">​]
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to try something like this

```
var author = $('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```

some other examples

```
$("meta[property=og:title]").attr("content", document.title);
$("meta[property=og:url]").attr("content", location.toString());
```

one more example from google only

```
var mt = $('meta[name=some-name]');
mt = mt.length ? mt : $('<meta name="some-name" />').appendTo('head');
mt.attr('content', 'some value');
```

Answer (score 2):

When accessing facebook meta tags:
If you get

```
"uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [property=fb:app_id]"
```

You need to quote the property name of FB meta tags:

```
myApp2 = $('meta[property="fb:app_id"]').attr("content") ;
```

Comment: While this seems to be true, it's not closely related to the question.

Comment: The need to use quotes seems an important note

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript escape function to post HTML tags in jquery,
use this to select meta tag

```
escape( $(data).find("meta") )
```

Comment: Definitely not usefull. escape an object array ? what for?